# find all the possible occurence of a substring in a string

Tags: c++, string, substring

how can i find all the possible occurrence of a sub string like rr in arrraarrra ? the answer to this question must be 6. As rrr can have 3 rr's in it and the second pair of rrr can also have rr in it .
for better understanding another example is finding lol in lolol where the answer is 4 as , taking lolol as index {0,1,2,3,4}
the combinations are {0,1,2} , {2,3,4} , {0,1,4} and {0,3,4}.

please help me

Comment: That's two different problems in your examples. In the first case the answer should be 15, because of cases when first `r` from `rr` is in the beginning of `arrraarrra`, and the second `r` is in the end.

Comment: Use `std::search` or `std::string::find` and iterate the string using the previous index location.

Comment: Please search StackOverflow for "c++ find possible occurrences substring".  This has been answered many times, including today.